# Error: Visual Studio Code is running without SUID sandbox

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to run the Visual Studio Code and I am getting this error .

```
[7188:1101/165451:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(173)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
```

Running the latest version. 0.9.2
on centos 7
with kernel
4.2.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64

Comment: We have seen reports on this but it should not prevent VS Code from starting, or does it?

Comment: It is not opening at all. I waited for a long time but it is not opening.